# Avoid rebuilding artifacts in Jenkins multibranch pipelines

Tags: merge, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, artifact, rebuild

## TL;DR

How do I avoid rebuilding artifacts on master when a feature is merged without creating multiple pipelines per project? Where do I access the information about which branch was merged?

## More Info

I run Jenkins to build many projects stored in two different VCSs (Gitlab, Bitbucket). Auto-discovery for both VCSs work and create multi-branch pipelines for every project/branch/PR containing a Jenkinsfile ([Gitlab Branch Source Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-branch-source), [Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cloudbees-bitbucket-branch-source)).

Build artifacts get produced and stored on every build (e.g. docker images pushed to registry).

As I follow a feature branch workflow, these features get eventually merged into master, master will then be deployed in irregular intervals.

When doing the merge, there is an artifact already built and stored for this code(see appendix:1). It was built for the feature branch the code originated from (e.g. container mysuperapp:feat-add-better-things-3). I would like to take this artifact and promote it as the new master artifact (e.g. mysuperapp:master), avoiding a rebuild (and unit + integration testing everything).

But, merging a feature branch just kicks off a new build pipeline on branch master without any information about the merged branch (see appendix:2). This is correct behavior concerning master (new commit(s) where pushed) but prevents me from reacting to the merged branch (e.g. the aforementioned promoting or even just deleting unused artifacts). Is there any way to get the information, which branch was merged?

I am aware, that I can create a new pipeline listening for PR webhooks from my VCSs, running a pipeline to do the promotion and ignore builds on master completely. But this moves visibility of this process to a different pipeline and requires additional pipelines for projects, e.g. reducing the advantage of auto-discovery to 50% (have to create these merge pipelines for each project).

How can I keep the advantages of auto-discovery and visibility of executed steps while also executing something on a merge?

Ideas: Tag artifacts differently, but how (needs to be able to clean up correctly)? Parameterize pipelines and setup a single merge pipeline which re-triggers the pipeline 'push on master' with parameters of the merged branch. But can this be done without having to setup the webhooks for every project? Ask the VCSs via REST about which branch belonged to a commit?

Greets and thanks for the help you all! This may be a complicated one, but it would be so cool to get this to work. It's the last barrier for me to enable continuos delivery for a lot of projects!

Appendix:

1: I am also aware, that to have consistent builds, I have to enforce `--ff-only` merges. This question is not about the pitfalls of git but rather about the way to go with Jenkins.

2: Git provides me with the parent commits, I can easily find out, which *commit* was merged. But, especially using "Delete branch after merge", leaves me without the *branch* ref in git. Tagging my docker images with commits instead of branches leaves me with backtracking the last commit on each build to delete the old, obsolete build.

Comment: "When doing the merge, there is an artifact already built and stored for this code" - what makes you think that?

Comment: Artifacts get produced and stored on every push for every PR. PRs get merged, when development for them is finished and the pipeline ran successfully. Therefore, merging using a merge commit will produce the merge commit on master with 2 parents: the old version from master and the last pushed commit to the feature branch. This last commit was built by the last pipeline for this feature branch (which equals in this case the according PR).
At least I hope that's the case, correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Two PRs can get merged, where the result wasn't in any of the two. E.g. PR-1 adds file '1' and PR-2 adds file '2'. Nowhere it has *both* 1 and 2. There's a need to build in master.

Comment: Please see App. 1: this is not possible when enforcing `--ff-only` merges. When PR1 is merged, PR2 can only be merged if the changes are integrated first (either by merging from master to PR2 or by rebasing). With master beeing a protected branch (-> only changes on accepting a PR) and PRs only beeing acceptable with a successful pipeline (-> stored build artifact), it enforces PR2 to integrate the changes from PR1 before merging. This also keeps one from merging incompatible changes to master (e.g. PR1 changes conf file, PR2 changes conf interpreter -> git happy to merge but tests will fail)

Comment: If there are 10 open PRs and one has been merged, does it mean someone needs to do 9 rebases and trigger 9 builds? Anyway, maybe skipping the builds on master altogether and using docker re-tag after merge may solve the issue.

Comment: That would be correct: there will be 9 more builds. And I am totally aware that this sounds bad (believe me, I know ). But this is not the question, rather your second Point is exactly the question: how? How do I re-tag the image? I know how to do it by hand (using docker tag or the REST-API of my registry, that is not the problem). But how do I do this in Jenkins when my pipelines only get the information that there was a push, but not that this is a merge commit from branch xyz to master? How do I find the correct image to re-tag?

Comment: You may e.g. tag your image with last git commit id in PR, and upon merging (when it becomes last commit id in master) trigger a job that will get last commit id in master, look for that tag in registry, and add `latest` tag to the image.

Comment: That is correct. This solves discovery of the last built artifact on master, but will store (almost) every version pushed in the registry (minus in the case of docker that layers are only stored once). Additionally (with docker), if I pull the artifact before every build, I get caching for free (avoid rebuilding layers). But for this, I need to know the last successful build for this branch. Tagging with a commit requires me to walk back one commit at a time, trying to pull this one from the registry.
Honestly, I feel like doing a bad job explaining this, I'm sorry ^^. Thanks for your input!

Comment: You may re-tag the image in registry without pulling it by using REST API. I have the code that does this.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase the question, reading this now seems like i left out a lot ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209698/discussion-between-christoph-girstenbrei-and-maratc).